# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog.models'

Tags: django

I was experimenting with my database and made some errors and messed up the whole database. I deleted the database and created a new blank db. When I go to makemigrations i get the error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog.models'` refering to the line in my views.py where i import my models. I tried creating a a new project and moving the files over same error. Everything was working fine before I messed up the DB. Sorry for not a ton of information I dont know what the issue really is

error

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 412, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\usera\djangoproject\django_coreyYT\urls.py", line 37, in <module>
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\usera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\usera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\usera\djangoproject\blog\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .views import PostDeleteView, ....... (all the models)
  File "C:\Users\usera\djangoproject\blog\views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .forms import PostForm, .... (all the models)
  File "C:\Users\usera\djangoproject\blog\forms.py", line 3, in <module>
    from blog.models import Post ... (all the models)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog.models'
```

**update**
I tried switching to my production DB and i am still getting the same error

Comment: You definitely have a `blog.models` file? Can you share it's contents and your project structure

Comment: @IainShelvington turns out it somehow got deleted thanks for your comment!